# how to convert an HTML template into Cake PHP template

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I'm a beginner in cake php. i have needed to convert my HTML template into Cake PHP template. any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is very easy.

1. Replace your template main file extension to .ctp
2. `index.html` to `index.ctp`
3. Look at the layout of you file (html code) and determine what section of that template you want to appear on all pages;
4. Usually most templates are setup as follows:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>My Site</title>
       // You will include your javascript and css files here
       <?php
           echo $this->Html->css(array('cake.generic','default'));
           echo $this->Html->script(array('myscript','jquery'));
       ?>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="container">
           <div id="header"></div>
           <div id="body">
               <div id="main_content" style="width:600px;float:left">
                      <?php 
                           //Code for this should be in your home.ctp
                           // in your pages folder. Usually I cut this content from
                           // my template and place the whole thing in that file
                           // everything else happens magically
                           echo $content_for_layout; 
                      ?>
               </div>
               <div id="side_content" style="width:300px;float:left">
                    <!-- You can have content here manually or create elements and include them here like the following -->
                    <?php $this->element("sidebar_content"); ?>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div id="footer">...</div>
       </div>
    </body>
   ```
5. You should then upload all images to the `/img` folder in your `/app/webroot` folder
6. Change your images path to reference `/img` folder.
7. You must do the same with all your CSS and JS files. Place them in their corresponding folders in the `/app/webroot` location.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Save your template in to `APP/views/layouts/template.ctp`.

Make sure it has at least two variables:

`<title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>`

and

```
<body>
    <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
</body>
```

Fire up your view, or controller and add
`$this->layout = 'template'; // view/method`
or `$layout = 'template'; // controller;`

Look at the Cake `default.ctp` for ideas.